# Get user group ID by login user id in joomla?

Tags: joomla

How to get user **group ID** by login user id in Joomla?
I try this
`$user  = JFactory::getUser();
$user_groups = $user->groups;`
this return an array.
I want only current group ID.
And is this possible to disable admin menu in Joomla and redirect to any component.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the relevant code snippets you have tried yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code -

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$groups = $user->get('groups');

foreach($groups as $group) {
    echo "<p>You're group ID is:" . $group . "</p>";
}
```